# How to make "primeng-turbo" table responsive functionality same as like "jquery datatable" responsive functionality?

Tags: jquery, datatables, angular7, primeng-turbotable

I'm using primeng library with angular 7 and i need some help in " turbo table" responsive design.

Right now they offering their default responsive design, same as given in below link

[Existing view: Primeng Table Responsive](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7.1.3/#/table/responsive/)

**Or**

[Screenshots for existing view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk71z.png)

But actualy i want design same as like "jquery datatable" responsive design in primeng table.

[Expected view: Jquery Datatable Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/responsive.html)

**Or**

[Expected view in primeng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyCwt.png)

Is it possible to do it in angular 7 with primeng?
Does anyone have any idea, Please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps row expand [feature](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion).?

I think you can use ngIf to toggle the row expansion column when your viewport gets mobile sized.